# ASP.NET MVC3: What is the quickest way to access a DB and get a few rows?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

Currently I am using a DLL Library to get lists of custom objects.

Which is all great, for being able to use it in other projects.

**But I want a dropdown box, which is a lookup of a DB table, with literally 3 options, (High, medium, low) and this isnt the only case that this is a problem.**

**Is there any short way of getting such info?**

In ROR you could literally call SQL String to a db and get the list, with just one line of code.....

So Id like something like:

```
var mylist = sqldb.query("SELECT * FROM Priority");
```

Note: yes the above is completely made up.

Ideally I wouldnt have to set up any models either... and ideally also not have to attach a DB, rather use a query string- unless attaching is far easier and can be customised from the config file.

**Update:**
following an example, I now ahve the following, but it says `System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.`

```
    using (var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(WebLite.Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnString))
    {
        var items = db.Query("SELECT * FROM TaskPriority");
    }
```

My connection string: `Data Source=MYPC\WEB;Initial Catalog=WEBSQL;User ID=sa;Password=password;`

Comment: Do you want quick and dirty or solid and maintainable?

Comment: @jrummell: Everyone wants quick and maintainable but end up with dirty and solid.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL?  In the EF you could do a data first project and have your quick and dirty models.

Comment: MVC. And I just want something thats very light on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Database` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) from WebMatrix.Data:

```
var items = Database.Open(...).Query("SELECT * FROM Priority");
```

However, in the long run, using Entity Framework will be more maintainable.

Comment: And this will close it up afterwards? i.e. no maintance

Comment: Yes, although you should put the `Database` in a `using` block.

Comment: You can also use this with LINQ.

Comment: I put my connection strin in the brackets, and it just says connection string "mystring" was not found. :@

Comment: @Doomsknight: Put the connection string in `Web.config` and pass the name.  Or just call `OpenConnectionString`.  See the documentation.

Comment: Please can you see my update, to my Q, and tell me where i have gone wrong. thanks. (its not liking my connection string)

Comment: @Doomsknight: It's using the wrong provider.  You should put the connection string in `<connectionStrings>` in Web.config (not in `<appSettings>`) with the correct `providerName`, then call `Open` with the connection strings' name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a database table to fetch a couple of rows you have a few options:

- Linq to Sql
- Entity Framework
- DataSets / TableAdapter
- Raw sql with your own connection/command.

I think the last option is the most easy. Your code would look something like this:

```
 string queryString = 
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                    reader[0], reader[1]));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

Define your connection string to your database and pass it in. Then build your sql query, open a connection, build the command and then read trough the rows returned.

Comment: Thats currently what i do do, and in the while reader loop, I populate a custom class list. But thanks. Going to research the other methods, you and others suggest

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution:

1. Create a new LINQ to SQL model (and open it).
2. Drag the `Priority` table on the model (and save it).
3. Query the model like this: `(new MyDataContext()).Priorities`.

Answer (score 1):

THe Microsoft Enterprise Library has the "Data Access Application Block" that makes connections to data extremely easy. The information can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664408(v=PandP.50).aspx

You can create a connection and get data using this code (from https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111631/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070203-1.aspx)

```
string strSql = "select * from products where categoryid = 1";
string strConnTxt = "Server=(local);Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;";

DataGrid4.DataSource = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(strConnTxt, CommandType.Text, strSql);
DataGrid4.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org) or maybe [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) sounds closest to what you're looking for.
Stolen from their example page:

```
   public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }
}            

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });

dog.Count()
    .IsEqualTo(1);

dog.First().Age
    .IsNull();

dog.First().Id
    .IsEqualTo(guid);
```